# Should the response argument to `process_response` always be a subclass of HttpResponse?

Tags: django, middleware

Question is in the title. Found that when our views raise `Http404` exception, the response argument to our `process_response` methods is an exception instead of an `HttpResponse`.

Is this correct? Do we need to account for such cases when writing middleware or is something misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it looks like a duck, and quacks like a duck...

But yes, your `process_response()` method should receive a `HttpResponse` subclass, not an exception. If your middleware receives an exception, it is most likely caused by returning a `Http404`, instead of raising it, in the view or a previous middleware method.

Comment: I created a test view that does `raise Http404` and confirmed it ends up being passed in as the response object in `process_response`. What do you make of that?

Comment: Found the problem. The issue was that another middleware was overriding `process_exception` and improperly returning the `Http404` exception as a response. Thanks for the duckiness! I marked your reply as the solution.